# Table - DotVVM.Framework.Controls.Bootstrap

Tags: dotvvm

I'm using control , and I ask if I can get their values and manipulate like a GridView ?? and use the values in the ViewModel. If possible you could tell me how would the procedure.

regards

Answer (score 0):

The **Bootstrap for DotVVM** package contains the `<bs:GridView>` control which inherits from the default `<dot:GridView>` control, it only adds it few additional properties so the rendered table uses Bootstrap styling.

Look at the [documentation of the Bootstrap GridView control](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/controls/bootstrap/GridView/latest).

The `<bs:Table>` is only a simple wrapper over the `<table>` element, nothing special.